# Add form elements to one form element 

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok ,

Lets say I am creating a form. And its an address form,form elements as such :

```
field 1 / house number
field 2 / street name
field 3 / suburb 
etc etc etc
```

And someone fills in the form,:

```
1
smith street
townsville
```

What I want ( similar to stack overflows live form )
Is another form element, that propagates the form field entries LIVE but replaces spaces with text:

So it appears like: `1+snith+street+townsville`

With a search button at the end. This then triggers the rest of the script we have already done, which basicaly grabs the lat and long of the address and displays a gmap.

Thats essentially it, but we would need that all this occurs, whilst on the form, and before submission.

Any help appreciated, have asked several other places. No joy, but always use StackOverflow..
Thanks Ozzy

Comment: "...have asked several other places. No joy, but always use StackOverflow.." - I'm trying to understand this, and it might just bother me the rest of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#my_form input').change(function() {
  var new_text = '';
  $('#my_form input').each(function() {
    new_text += $.trim($(this).val()).replace(' ', '+') + '+';
  });
  $('#my_display').val(new_text);
});
```

Comment: Could you please script up this as an example?

Comment: Sorry, I had just a couple of changes in my code. Check this out on jsfiddle though. It should be what you need http://jsfiddle.net/mrK4T/

Comment: Cheers Aaron, thats nearly 100% Could we also add search button. ?

Comment: Hmm, are you asking for the code that does the search too? Or just what the tag looks like in HTML?

Comment: Essentially, what you created is brilliant. But rather than plonking the result into a div , it really needs to be in a search field, with search button. Essentially, if you look at this guys gmap script, we need for what you did, to be plonked into the search field: link -http://plugins.jquery.com/project/locationpicker

Comment: I see. Check this one out then http://jsfiddle.net/mrK4T/1/. But I'm curious, are you sure you even need to add all of the '+'s? I'm pretty sure you can get away with just a space separated string for that plugin. At least it worked for me that way.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, emailed you via your website to say many many thanks. We should be good to go now, this has stumped me for days lol. Yeah I wanted to add the + symbols, not sure at all why now. Respect and marked best answer

Comment: to add I would vote up, but need more rep. I havent ever posted here before, only read tons of stuff. :) Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

here something that might work. . .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('body').live('keypress', function (event) {

    if ($(event.target).hasClass('form-element')) {
      var text;
      $('#yourform input.form-element').each(function() {
        text += $(this).attr('value') + '+';
      });

      $('#yourtargetelementthatwillholdallthenames').attr('value', text.substring(0,text.length - 1))
    }

  });

});
```

i haven't tried this in a browser, but give it a shot. It might need some tweaking for your needs.

Comment: Could you better explain please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're submitting this for a search, use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead so you encode everything needed, like this:

```
$("#form1 input[type=text]").bind("keyup change", function() {
  var vals = $("#form1 input[type=text]").map(function() { return this.value; });
  $("#otherField").val(encodeURIComponent(vals.join(" ")));
});
```

Comment: Could you please script up this as an example?

Comment: Sorry Nick, I meant knock up a demo. I am not very good with js, or jQuery. And not knowing how to bind the listener to the form elements.

Comment: Its on a non public project. I can email you link, and screenshots of what we are trying to achieve

Comment: @user501173 - just the `<form>` markup itself will do, for example on jsfiddle:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8qswj/

Comment: sorry the form is already embedded into our webpage, and is large. Plus lots of dependencies. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user501173 - then your question isn't well suited for SO...questions here are to help *others* as well, not sites, links and code no one else can see/benefit from.